# ROWLOCK in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table to update with no indexing in the where clause so I use ROWLOCK in the update script, hoping to get row lock instead of table lock but no luck.. so what is the function of the ROWLOCK then? I was using it in the select statement but still locking the entire table... so annoying!

> DBCC TRACEON (-1, 3604, 1200)
>
> BEGIN TRAN
>
> UPDATE [Order]
>
> with (ROWLOCK)
>
> SET ProductId = 3
>
> WHERE CustomerId = 1

**TRACE OUTPUT:**

> DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your
>   system administrator.
>
> Process 54 acquiring IX lock on OBJECT: 16:229575856:0 (class
>   bit2000000 ref1) result: OK
>
> Process 54 acquiring IU lock on PAGE: 16:1:196 (class bit0 ref1)
>   result: OK
>
> Process 54 acquiring U lock on RID: 16:1:196:0 (class bit0 ref1)
>   result: OK
>
> Process 54 acquiring IX lock on PAGE: 16:1:196 (class bit2000000 ref0)
>   result: OK
>
> Process 54 acquiring X lock on RID: 16:1:196:0 (class bit2000000 ref0)
>   result: OK
>
> Process 54 releasing lock reference on RID: 16:1:196:0
>
> Process 54 acquiring U lock on RID: 16:1:196:1 (class bit0 ref1)
>   result: OK
>
> Process 54 releasing lock on RID: 16:1:196:1
>
> Process 54 releasing lock reference on PAGE: 16:1:196
>
> (1 row(s) affected)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You **ARE** getting row locks!

See [Understanding Locking in SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213039%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) to understand why a ROWLOCK update must acquire hierarchical **intent** locks, for an explanation of the `Process 54 acquiring IU lock on PAGE: 16:1:196 (class bit0 ref1) result: OK`.

Comment: From the linked page: "An intent lock indicates that SQL Server wants to acquire a shared (S) lock or exclusive (X) lock on some of the resources lower down in the hierarchy."

Answer (score 0):

Its all OK - only ROWLOCK was taken over updated rows, and as I said in your previous post - Intent locks over PAGE and TABLE also held - its by design

Comment: if it is by design to lock on page/table then why even bother to do a row lock?

Comment: @ronald_yoh Please, read the BOL about intent locking